# trying to check textbox value against values in a dataset column

Tags: c#

Im trying to check a textbox value against row values of a specific column, my code works but checks all the columns and I cant figure out how to get it to check just the CompanyName column. Any ideas?

```
 private void BTNLookupCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BTNUpdateCustomer.Enabled = false;
        BTNDeleteCustomer.Enabled = false;



        try
        {
            if (TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text != null)
            {
                foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
                        {
                            if (item.ToString() == TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text)
                            {
                                BTNUpdateCustomer.Enabled = true;
                                BTNDeleteCustomer.Enabled = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{

   if (row["CompanyName"].ToString() == TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text)
   {
      BTNUpdateCustomer.Enabled = true;
      BTNDeleteCustomer.Enabled = true;
      break; // condition matched break loop here no need to iterate further
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataRow.Field<Typename>("ColumnName")`:

```
bool isEnteredNameEqual = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Any(row => row.Field<string>("CompanyName") == TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text)
BTNUpdateCustomer.Enabled = isEnteredNameEqual;
BTNDeleteCustomer.Enabled = isEnteredNameEqual;
```

Note that above uses LINQ, so you need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file. Note also that `TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text != null` is redundant since a `TextBox.Text` property never returns `null` even if you assign null. You might want to use `String.IsNullOrEmtpty` or  `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead.

The same with a classic loop:

```
BTNUpdateCustomer.Enabled = false;
BTNDeleteCustomer.Enabled = false;

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   string companyName = row.Field<string>("CompanyName");
   if(companyName == TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text)
   {
       BTNUpdateCustomer.Enabled = true;
       BTNDeleteCustomer.Enabled = true;
       break;
   }
}
```